# Programmatically getting Linux device resource info

Tags: c, linux

I was given some resource list to get value of them programmatically in C. Although I know these are too specific and is not really important or generic, still due to my intelligent boss, I just wanted to have opinion about the list. Remember it may run in any type of Linux based device , may be desktop, laptop even in embedded devices like rpi or edison, gallileo

```
SERIAL_NO /*vendor specific*/
BATTERY_LEVEL /*not generic*/
HEAP /*only program specific*/
CPU_FREQUENCY /*vendor specific register*/
PROCESSOR_TYPE /*vendor specific register*/
PROCESSOR_SPEED /*vendor specific register*/
STORAGE /*I am not really sure*/
MODEL /*vendor specific register*/
IMEI /*vendor specific driver, not generic*/
DEVICE_TYPE /*vendor specific register*/
ALTITUDE /*vendor specific sensor, not generic*/
SPEED /*vendor specific sensor*/
BEARING /*vendor specific*/
```

If anyone have any suggestion, be it technical or strategic, please advice me. Tired of such illogical requirements. Sorry if anyway I violated SO rules.

Comment: Find existing programs that provide that info and extract means to determine the values from their sourcecode or by reverse engineering. Which of these is giving you problems, btw? That said, some strategic advise: Find a job that doesn't make you unhappy.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am considering your strategic suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Find tools that dump/use the info you are looking for and `strace`
   them to get an idea on where to look for this info
2. Find opensource tools that dump/use the info you are looking for and
   read the code
3. Look into `/proc`, for example `cpuinfo`

Comment: technically POSIX API should be better. syscalls via shell into C is not really a good programming exercise.

Comment: syscalls via shell into C? do you mean C into shell?

Comment: I mean system calls from C like cat /proc/cpuinfo, calling this from C is not a good practice

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on what are the types of the devices you're interesting (network adaptor, block device etc). For many of them the usual way to get some info can be the `sysctl` which provides you a native C API which means the solution is supposed to be portable between all platforms supporting this device. So, what you may do is to search what exact driver handles your device and see what sysctls it supports. For this you need either read its header file[s], or its implementation or its doc if present. `man sysctl` for reference. However I don't know any kind of a "generic" way to get info of a random device.

Comment: That's what, correctly said. But you know some people are like that. Hard to deal with some people.